# How to detect if browser is running any javascript (without changing js on page)

Tags: javascript, browser, selenium

I'm working on implementation of custom php client for selenium and I have a problem with implementing `waitForPageToLoad()` function:

the problem is that just checking `document.readyState` is not enough - there could be some JS script running on the page (for example, some animation after button click) that should force my `waitForPageToLoad()` function to continue waiting, but `document.readyState` returns `complete` status in such case.

Another problem is that I can't use callbacks as I don't know what js will be run on a page. Nonetheless I can insert some js on page but I must be sure that it will NOT influence on page's normal behavior.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution?
Currently I'm working with latest FF browser.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 to the above, at least, there is no reliable way.

Comment: Please note this is the exact reason the WebDriver API has no concept of `waitForPageToLoad()`. In a world where the DOM is ever-changing due to JavaScript, "the page is fully loaded" is a concept that is impossible to apply in a one-size-fits-all way.

Comment: well, thanks. I had the same opinion, but needed a confirmation to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check if JavaScript is currently running.

You can wait for elements to be present.

For Python, it would work like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  # noqa

driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)

el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a"))  # change to your needs
)
```

See also: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html